# External Links Changing Same Tab

Tags: html, hyperlink, href, external-links

I'm using target="_blank", the link opens in a New tab, but same tab ALSO goes to the target link. How do I stop this?! Why would BOTH current tab & new tab go to the link? Is the problem in my own settings? It happens to all of the external links on my site. Is there something on my website coding? Other websites' external links work just fine.. Please help!

Comment: Can you show the code-snipped?

Comment: please show your code to clarify your question.

Comment: This can be marked solved.. I think. For whatever reason, Chrome decided to mess with my brain.. It was just cache/cookies.. Why or how it happened, however, the world may never know. Thanks for the attempt to help; a friend told me to clear some content on Chrome and I realized it was just on my end. But if someone wants to answer a future question I'm sure someone will ask.... Why would chrome do this? How to prevent this? What's causing it? Thanks again SO Squad.